# Recorrer una tabla html con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img name="grid[0][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[0][1]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[0][2]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img name="grid[1][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[1][1]" src="azul.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[1][2]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img name="grid[2][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[2][1]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
<td><img name="grid[2][2]" src="rojo.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Como podría ir recorriendo la tabla y las imagenes para poder cambiarlas con javascript.
Mi intención era hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
            elementos[i][j]=document.getElementsByName("grid["+i+"]["+j+"]");
       }
 }
```

y luego hacer

```
elementos[2][1].src="azul.jpg";
```

pero esto no funciona
Como podría hacer para recorrer esos elementos con name=grid[i][j]
La tabla tiene 30 filas y 54 columnas asi que me sería complicado ir añadiendo cada elemento con

```
document.getElementsByName("grid[0][0]");document.getElementsByName("grid[0][1]");....
```

La intencion es hacer un juego similar al snake pero de dos jugadores y necesito que la imagen que muestre cada celda de la tabla vaya cambiando.
El problema es que el array elementos me dice que no está definido.

Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Explica **textualmente** lo que quieres hacer. No se sabe si quieres poner azul en todas las celdas o en una en específico en cada fila.

Comment: Me gustaría ir poniendo una celda en concreto (identificada por su fila y columna) con una imagen determinada. Es para un juego tipo snake pero de dos jugadores, cuando la serpiente se va moviendo la celda se colorea de rojo si es el jugador 1 o de azul si es el jugador 2, si es el fondo (no hay jugador en esa celda) permanece gris.

Comment: Haz clic en [edit] para agregar los detalles que mencionaste en tu comentario en la pregunta.

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse. ¿Qué celda en concreto y cómo se identifica el jugador en el contexto de tu código? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi solución fue la siguiente:
-declarar var elementos vacia

```
var elementos=[["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]];
```

y luego recorrer el array vacio asignandole elementos:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
       for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
                       
             var ele='grid['+i+']['+j+']';
                        
              elementos[i][j]=document.getElementsByName(ele);
                        
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No estabas tan mal encaminado, pero hay varios problemas con tu código:

1. Tienes atributos no asignados, como: `name "grid[0][1]"` y `src"gris.jpg"`, les falta el signo `=`
2. No estás inicializando el arreglo y tampoco creando las filas. Simplemente tratas de agregar las celdas
3. Deberías usar [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para agregar nuevos elementos
4. El método [.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) devuelve una lista de nodos, no importa si solo encuentra uno. Al asignar, deberías hacer referencia al primer elemento devuelto, ejemplo: `elementos[i][j] = document.getElementsByName("grid["+i+"]["+j+"]")[0];`

Una opción más fácil es crear el arreglo y recorrer las filas de la tabla, seleccionando directamente las imágenes para agregarlas:

```js
// Debes inicializar el arreglo
let elementos = [];
// Obtener tabla
let tableGrid = document.querySelector('#table-grid');

// Recorrer filas de la tabla
Array.from(tableGrid.rows).forEach((row, i) => {
    // Insertar imágenes por fila en el arreglo
    elementos.push(row.querySelectorAll('img'));
});

// Cada fila en elementos contiene un objeto con las imágenes
console.log(elementos);
// Pero puedes acceder a ellas por los índices que tienes definidos
console.log(elementos[1][2]);

// Cambiar src de una imagen
elementos[1][2].src = 'azul.jpg';
// Ver la imagen actualizada
console.log(elementos[1][2]);
```

```html
<table id="table-grid">
<tr>
    <td><img name="grid[0][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[0][1]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[0][2]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img name="grid[1][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[1][1]" src="azul.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[1][2]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img name="grid[2][0]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[2][1]" src="gris.jpg"></td>
    <td><img name="grid[2][2]" src="rojo.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: me resulto mas fácil mi solución aunque gracias por la respuesta.